# .htaccess rewrite all php files

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have wrote my rules to display all my php files etc work from work.php
so both can show. My .hataccess is as follow

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

the issue that i am having and i am not sure that htaccess can help with this is that, all of my code has .php appended in the end.
Is there an easy way to handle this ? Force .htaccess to change all the .php to nothing ? 
I am  pretty sure that is not possible and ill need to do a code review and change them all manually.

I hope that i said it out clear.

Thanx

Comment: Yes. RewriteRules only adapt the *incoming* URLs. The relative links in your HTML output need to be adapted in your code. -- One could issue temporary HTTP redirects via a second set of RewriteRules; but that would look silly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the code that you can use to hide .php extension. Put it inside .htaccess file in your $DOCUMENT_ROOT directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).php$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: assumes it's in the root. Though this is an old post, none of these answers worked for me, until I found one like this an modified it for the root of a subdomain. If it's a directory change the RewriteBase accordingly.