# .htaccess rewrite /foo/bar/ to /foo/bar.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to set rules in my .htaccess file so that all files with a .php extension can be accessed by replacing the extension with just a slash (`/foo/bar/` would silently load `/foo/bar.php`). Previously, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608413/htaccess-rewrite-all-php-files), which is kind of what I'm looking for, except it only changes `/foo/bar.php` to `/foo/bar` (notice there is no end slash).

I'm almost a completely newbie when it comes to htaccess, and about 30 minutes of tweaking with the code from the previous link produced nothing by a ton of `500 internal server error`s. I'm sure it's such a simple fix, but neither Google nor trial and error have yet to bring me any results.

Could anyone take a look at the code from the aforementioned post (copied below) and change it so that `/foo/bar/` will rewrite to `/foo/bar.php`?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments below, the intent is to have user-visible URLs like /foo/bar/ that actually run php scripts like /foo/bar.php. In addition, you probably want users who try to load /foo/bar.php directly to be redirected to /foo/bar/ for consistency.

```
#Redirect users loading /foo/bar.php to /foo/bar/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1/ [R]

#Rewrite /foo/bar/ (what the user sees) silently to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

The `[R]` at the end of the first rule specifies to redirect rather than rewrite, so that the user loads /foo/bar/. The `$1` at the end of the second rule matches the parentheses (everything prior to the terminating slash) then tacks .php on the end. The `[L]` means to stop evaluating `RewriteRules`.

As in my original reply, the use of a leading slash for the replacement string depends on context. With these rules you'll be able to see the effect of the first rule since it's a redirect. If the redirect tries to go to  `mydomain.comfoo/bar/` rather than `mydomain.com/foo/bar/`, then add a leading slash before the `$1` in each rule.

Another note - does your php script expect any query strings? There may need to be an additional tweak if it does.

The [Apache mod_rewrite reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) has more details.

Comment: This just produces `404 Not Found` errors all over the place.

Comment: Sorry, but `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1/` produces the same result. Still just showing 404 Not Found on every page.

Comment: You're too quick ... you tested it while I was editing to give the second option. :-) Just to make sure you understand, though, what you requested is to rewrite to `/foo/bar.php` to `/foo/bar/`. That doesn't mean that you're just hiding the ".php" part from the user, it means that Apache will actually try to load `/foo/bar/`. If you really want the bar.php script to be run, but the user to see just bar/, that's a different question.

Comment: My bad, I mean that I'm loading something like `/mypage.php`, but I would like the USER to see only `/mypage/`. The URLs would still point to `/mypage.php` though. My apologies if my original question was badly phrased.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it working with some modification to the code you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately I got this working using the following code, a combination of my original finding and David Ravetti's help.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L,NC]
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```