# How to make .html appear as / in .htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, directory, muse

My problem is this,
I want for example:

Make www.mywebsite.com/index.html 
Look/appear  (not redirect) like this
www.mywebsite.com/index/

so far I used below code and only obtained www.mywebsite.com/index look.
I will highlight that I don’t want to redirect, I want only to the html look like folder

I work in Adobe MUSE. I build websites mostly for fun and just want to focus on designing not coding

Here is my .htaccess script taken from here: [.htaccess rewrite /foo/bar/ to /foo/bar.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432305/htaccess-rewrite-foo-bar-to-foo-bar-php)

Please, can someone help me with it?
What line(s) should I change to have the folder appearance 
Thanks

```
Options  -MultiViews 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Za-z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Please referrer this [https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)

Comment: What do you mean by "I dont want to redirect"? It's a bit unclear ,please explain.

Comment: To be precise, I don't want to redirect, just replace a string of ".html" with "/" to make it look more - so to say - professional.